# UserControlを継承したPartial Classを子要素として表示したい

Tags: c#

環境はVisual Studio Community 2013です。

最初に、プロジェクトにMainControlという名前のUserControlを追加しました。しかし、開発しているうちにソースコードが長くなってしまったので、partialを使ってソースコードを2つに分けました。すると、新しく作成した"MainControl.Methods.cs"のアイコンが"C#ソースコード"から"ユーザーコントロール"になってしまい、ダブルクリックをするとフォームデザイナが開くようになってしまいました。F7を押せばコードを表示できるので、特に困ることはないのですが、何か他に より適切な方法はあるのでしょうか？ それともUserContolを継承するクラスをpartialで複数のファイルに分割するのは適切ではないでしょうか？

また、[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")] 属性を指定してみたのですが、効果がないようでした。これは Visual Studio 2013 でも動作するはずの機能なのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> それともUserContolを継承するクラスをpartialで複数のファイルに分割するのは適切ではないでしょうか？

問題ないです。

以下の手順を試してみてください。私はASP.NET (WebForms)で同様のことをしています。

[Qiita - Partialクラスのファイルを元クラスの子として表示](http://qiita.com/kobake@github/items/87239e4d50fe0031513c)

csprojファイル内で、`"MainControl.Methods.cs"`について`DependentUpon`の記述を追加し、親を指定してください。`<SubType>Code</SubType>`の指定もお忘れなく。